# Keyboard Shortcut for RoR pair of brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Ruby on Rails (RoR) document opened and want to make the `<%= %>` pair of brackets. In TextMate, it's under *Bundles > Ruby > Insert ERB's* and the key command looks like `^ >`

How do I type that on a Mac? I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Bracket</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the key combination

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>